# How to use jQuery variables in html

Tags: php, jquery, html

I'm coding a piece for a site where I need to pass some variables to the current php page (which has jQuery functions in it).

I need to use an html button press to pass variables from jQuery to the php page itself.

Here's the psuedo-function:

```
<?php

function foo($v1, v2) {}
?>
```

Here's the HTML I'd like to make work.

```
<input type="button" onclick="foo([JQVariable 1], [JQVariable 2])" value="Derp" />
```

Any suggestions to either do this or make it easier?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? Once the data is submitted, do you want to further process the resulting data in Javascript? Or, do you want to just make the button to the equivalent of submitting a form with certain data?

Answer (score 0):

**This is what you will need :**

JQuery on the page with your button :

```
function foo(var1, var2) {
    $.post('path/to/page.php', { v1: var1 , v2: var2 }, function(data) {
      $('#div').html(data);
    });
}
```

With the above you are going to **post** `v1` and `v2` to **page.php** and then **load the content of page.php** into `#div`.

On page.php :

```
$v1 = $_POST['v1'];
$v2 = $_POST['v2'];
function foo($v1, $v2){
    // run your function here... 
}

// the output is loaded onto 'button page'
```

With JQuery `.post()`, `.get()` or `.load()` your users can load content/data from your diffrent scripts/pages by clicking on buttons, etc.. without leaving the current page. It's basically all about bypassing the browser-refresh on a post-back.

**Note :** you may also want to look at `$.post("page.php", $("#testform").serialize());`

You can find the [documentation here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/).

Hope it helps.